# Displaying new set of thumbnails in Configurable Product Swatches

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, swatches, color-swatches

So, this question has been asked multiple times in the past and yet I didn't find an answer for it.

I am running Magento 1.9.2 which comes with Configurable Product Swatches. Now I can display product image according to the selected color.

**However, Is it possible to load a whole set of new images when user change the color value, instead of only changing 1 image per Color?**

For example: Let's say I have T-shirt with different colors, and I want to display front and back of the T-shirt accordingly to the color.

Putting both front and back of the T-shirt in 1 image is NOT the solution.

**If this is not supported by default in Magento, Is there any plugin that can guarantee this feature?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well right now this feature is not provided by magento,

But you can use below extension created by Marius and it has the same feature that you want,

It provide same functionality and provide some other good features to and best thing its free.

https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher

Comment: I installed the module recommended by you, and it works perfectly!